# how to prevent all pipe redirections from getting appended to a file

Tags: list, shell, hadoop, pipe

I am trying the following hadoop command in unix.

```
*hadoop fs -ls <HDFS path> | grep MatchValue | cut -d "/" f11*
```

or

```
*hadoop fs -ls <HDFS path> | sed -e '/MatchValue/!d' | cut -d "/" f11*
```

I get the desired output what I intended.

Now here comes my problem. I am trying to redirect this output to a file in shell script.

```
hadoop fs -ls <HDFS path> | sed -e '/MatchValue/!d' | cut -d "/" f11 >> LogName.lst
```

or

```
hadoop fs -ls <HDFS path> | sed -e '/MatchValue/!d' | cut -d "/" f11 1>> LogName1>.lst 2>> LogName2.lst
```

Now in the logs I am also getting first and second pipe results also.

I also tried with only first pipe two commands alone without cut, even there I am getting the hadoop command results too.

I tried this approach both ksh and bash. No use.

Answer (score 1):

No by using pipe you won't get stdout content of previous piped commands in the chain. Most likely you are getting stderr content.

Try this command to suppress error:

```
hadoop fs -ls 2>/dev/null | sed -e '//!d' | cut -d "/" f11 >> .lst
```

Comment: No use. I am still getting all results.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output of this command `hadoop fs -ls 2>/dev/null | head`

Comment: Hi Anubhav. Thanks for your help. I sorted it out myself. Since I appended the results to the file, My previous attempts results were also found file. Pipe command works perfectly fine.